# RTL Language string placeholder in android studio

Tags: android, string, android-studio, right-to-left

I would like to ask is it possible to update/edit RTL languages with placeholders?

Other languages will correctly display the **%1$s** placeholder but in RTL languages is **s$1%**. Hence, it will crash if the placeholder will be replaced using

```
getString(R.string.sample, "mystring");
```

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

You can try concatenating the String, or appending substring to a StringBuilder.
Then `TextView.setText(<the result of concatenation>)` (Java) or `TextView.text = <the result of concatenation>` (Kotlin).

Yes, this is just a workaround, and even Android Studio tooltips doesn't recommend it and will show a warning, because by doing so, it can't handle locale changes if your app support multiple languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this s$%1 for RTL languages.

Comment: and how to implement this? since I've stated on my question that it will crash.